# Clean map periodically

Tags: c++, stdmap, stddeque

I have a A class managing a map.

```
class A {
 public:
  A() {}
  void addElem(uint8_t a, const B& b) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
    auto result = _map.emplace_hint(_map.end(), a, b);
    _deque.push_back(std::make_pair(result, time(nullptr)));
  }
  void cleanMap() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
    _map.erase(_deque.front().first);
    _deque.pop_front();
  }
 private:
  std::map<uint8_t, B> _map;
  std::deque<std::pair<std::map<uint8_t, B>::iterator, time_t>> _deque;
  std::mutex _mutex;
};
```

As I add a lot of elements in my map, I want to periodically clean it by removing elements that were first inserted.

```
if (difftime(time(nullptr), _deque.front().second > EXPIRY)) {
  cleanMap();
}
```

The following code is crashing at some point when I try to pop element from deque:

```
double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00007fffdc000900 ***
```

Is the above code makes sense ? If yes, where could be the error ? And if not, how can I clean periodically a map ?

Comment: `periodically` - how and when and from where do you call the cleanMap function? Is it another thread?

Comment: I have a thread that called periodically the cleanMap function.

Comment: Off topic but, as you've added a mutex to your code you should probably prefer the RAII style of (un)locking provided by e.g. [`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) rather than explicit calls to lock/unlock.

Comment: @G.M. I edited my post, thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have problems when you add the elements with the same key.

When `emplace_hint` is called with the key which exists, you push on deque duplicated iterators (`emplace_hint` returns the iterator to already existing element [map::emplace_hint](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace_hint)).
When deque and map are cleared, you call `map::erase` but it accepts only valid and dereferenceable iterators. So when `erase` is called for the duplicated iterator ([map::erase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase)), the code crashes because this item was deleted in previous `erase` call.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, you are probably right. So I need to check existence of the key and not pushing duplicated iterators ?

Comment: Yep, you need to find out how to store unique iterators, not duplicated.

Comment: @klaus Yes. Use `std::map::try_emplace`, which tells you whether the key already existed. Using `emplace_hint` only makes sense if you're sure that `a` increases from call to call. I mean, if you know that then just check for existence beforehand, but it's not clear from the example whether `emplace_hint` serves a purpose here.

Comment: I added in elements in queue only when I was sure I did not add duplicated elements in my map and it worked. Do I need to protect addElem and cleanMap with mutex?

Comment: @klaus You added a comment under your question that you clean map from a thread, so you have to protect access to the map.